# Store formatting for parts of strings

Tags: c#

Suppose we have a string and we want to format different parts of it differently (like in Word). My goal here was to create a data structure that can hold all the various parts of the string as character ranges and store the formatting used for each.

The user of this data structure should be able to call something like the following function to set the cell formatting for the characters 5 to 10 of the string. The complexity of this problem lies on the fact that a newly set range may intersect with or override one or many existing ranges.

```
var partialFormatting = new PartialFormatting();
partialFormatting.setCharacterRangeProperties(5, 10, new Formatting());
```

The solution I came up with includes a `CharacterRange` class which can handle each range of characters. Some of the contents of this class may seem weird, which is probably because I ended up using it within a `SortedDictionary`:

```
internal class CharacterRange : IComparable
{
    // Character ranges are compared solely based on their start numbers.
    public static bool operator >(CharacterRange a, CharacterRange b) => a.m_start > b.m_start;
    public static bool operator <(CharacterRange a, CharacterRange b) => a.m_start < b.m_start;
    public static bool operator >=(CharacterRange a, CharacterRange b) => a.m_start >= b.m_start;
    public static bool operator <=(CharacterRange a, CharacterRange b) => a.m_start <= b.m_start;

    private int m_start;
    private int m_end;

    public CharacterRange(int start, int end) {
        m_start = start;
        m_end = end;
    }

    public int start => m_start;
    public int end => m_end;
    public int length => m_end - m_start + 1;

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        CharacterRange other = obj as CharacterRange;
        if (other == null) return false;

        return m_start == other.m_start && m_end == other.m_end;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 31 + m_start.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + m_end.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }

    internal bool intersects(CharacterRange other) {
        // Contained within or right on bounds.
        if ((other.m_start >= m_start && other.m_start <= m_end) ||
            (other.m_end >= m_start && other.m_end <= m_end)) {
            return true ;
        } 
        // One range fully contains the other.
        else if (contains(other) || other.contains(this)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    internal bool contains(CharacterRange other) {
        if (m_start < other.m_start && m_end > other.m_end) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj) {
        CharacterRange other = (CharacterRange) obj;
        if (other is null) {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Object not of type {nameof(CharacterRange)}.");
        }

        if (this.GetHashCode() < other.GetHashCode()) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (this.GetHashCode() > other.GetHashCode()) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The `PartialFormatting` is responsible for keeping track of the character ranges as the user adds or removes arbitrary formatting ranges.

```
internal class PartialFormatting
{
    public class CharacterRangeComparer : IComparer<CharacterRange>
    {
        public int Compare(CharacterRange cr1, CharacterRange cr2) {
            return cr1.CompareTo(cr2);
        }
    }

    private SortedDictionary<CharacterRange, Formatting> m_charactedRangeProperties = new SortedDictionary<CharacterRange, Formatting>(new CharacterRangeComparer());

    internal SortedDictionary<CharacterRange, Formatting> charactedRangeProperties => m_charactedRangeProperties;

    internal void setCharacterRangeProperties(int start, int end, Formatting formatting) {
        if (formatting is null) {
            return;
        }
        if (start < 0) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Character range must start from 0.");
        }
        if (end < start) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("End of range cannot be less than the start.");
        }

        CharacterRange cr = new CharacterRange(start, end);
        if (!m_charactedRangeProperties.ContainsKey(cr)) {
            m_charactedRangeProperties.Add(cr, formatting);
            overwriteContainedRanges(cr);
            handleIntersectingCharacterRanges(cr);
        }
        else {
            m_charactedRangeProperties[cr] = formatting;
        }
    }

    private void overwriteContainedRanges(CharacterRange newRange) {
        var rangesToOverwrite = m_charactedRangeProperties.Keys.Where(cr => newRange.contains(cr) && !newRange.Equals(cr)).ToList();
        foreach (var range in rangesToOverwrite) {
            m_charactedRangeProperties.Remove(range);
        }
    }

    private void handleIntersectingCharacterRanges(CharacterRange newRange) {
        var ranges = m_charactedRangeProperties.Keys.ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < ranges.Count; i++) {
            var currentRange = ranges[i];
            // Skip self.
            if (currentRange.Equals(newRange)) {
                continue;
            }

            // Check if the new range is fully contained in the other one.
            if (currentRange.contains(newRange)) {
                // Splice the current range in three pieces.
                Formatting formatting = m_charactedRangeProperties[currentRange];
                CharacterRange truncatedStart = new CharacterRange(currentRange.start, newRange.start - 1);
                CharacterRange truncatedEnd = new CharacterRange(newRange.end + 1, currentRange.end);
                m_charactedRangeProperties.Remove(currentRange);
                m_charactedRangeProperties.Add(truncatedStart, formatting);
                m_charactedRangeProperties.Add(truncatedEnd, formatting);
            }
            else if (currentRange.intersects(newRange)) {
                if (currentRange < newRange) {
                    // Truncate the previous range.
                    Formatting formatting = m_charactedRangeProperties[currentRange];
                    CharacterRange truncated = new CharacterRange(currentRange.start, newRange.start - 1);
                    m_charactedRangeProperties.Remove(currentRange);
                    m_charactedRangeProperties.Add(truncated, formatting);
                }
                else {
                    // Truncate the next range.
                    Formatting formatting = m_charactedRangeProperties[currentRange];
                    CharacterRange truncated = new CharacterRange(newRange.end + 1, currentRange.end);
                    m_charactedRangeProperties.Remove(currentRange);
                    m_charactedRangeProperties.Add(truncated, formatting);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can tell by looking at it that there are much better solutions, so feel free to pick at it.

Comment: if `private m_start` then how is it able to be used: `other.m_start`?

Comment: `Overlays` a better name for method `contains`?  `intersects` & `contains` is confusing because `contains` is redundant to `intersects`.  What's this apparent special case about?

Comment: The ```contains``` method is just to differentiate between a range that is fully contained and can therefore be completely discarded, or if the newly created range is fully within an existing one and will therefore split it in three parts (notice the lack of = sign in the comparisons within ```contains```).

The ```intersects``` method is used to check if they overlap in any form. I use it after checking for ```contains``` and it wouldn't work properly otherwise.

I agree that this part of the algorithm seems fishy.

Comment: [equal hash codes do not imply object equality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35866246/463206)

Answer (score 3):

**CharacterRange.CompareTo**

`if ... else if` is functionally dead code; well, the `else if` part. Instead do this:

```
 if (other == null) return 1;   // see below
 if (this.GetHashCode() < other.GetHashCode())   return -1;
 if (this.GetHashCode() > other.GetHashCode())   return 1;
 return 0;
```

I love how one-line-if cleans up the semantic clutter. Faster to read and understand. Be sure to leave whites space to separate from other code blocks.

---

`if(other is null)` exception:

Just `return 1` -> "this" is greater than "null". CompareTo just defines sort order and "null" sorts to the bottom. An incompatible type object notwithstanding, just ignore it. It will not break downstream processing. Well, that's what testing is for.

In `Equals` the null is ignored; same idea applies here.

Can we say throwing a wrong type exception in `CompareTo` is a violation of Single Responsibility? What high-level code is not doing it's job by accepting randomly typed objects in the first place?

If you implement the generic:  `IComparable<CharacterRange>` then the parameter is type safe:

```
public int CompareTo(CharacterRange other) { ... }
```

---

---

**SetCharacterRangeProperties**

(I capitalized **S**et..)

Here for sure is a Single Responsible Principle violation.  This code *obviously* belongs in the `CharacterRange` constructor.

```
  if (formatting is null) {
        return;
    }
    if (start < 0) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Character range must start from 0.");
    }
    if (end < start) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("End of range cannot be less than the start.");
    }
```

---

The next code block belongs in a class that already, sort of, exists: a custom `CharacterRange` collection. (See below)

```
CharacterRange cr = new CharacterRange(start, end);
    if (!m_charactedRangeProperties.ContainsKey(cr)) {
        m_charactedRangeProperties.Add(cr, formatting);
        overwriteContainedRanges(cr);
        handleIntersectingCharacterRanges(cr);
```

---

---

**PartialFormatting is *Almost* a Custom Collection Class**

This class is managing the `SortedDictionary` collection but needs some key methods as seen in .NET provided collections.

By containing, vice inheriting, `SortedDictionary` we hide its public interface and provide our own

```
public void Add (CharacterRange newGuy, Formatting formatting) {
  if (newGuy == null) return;
  if (m_charactedRangeProperties.ContainsKey(newGuy)) return;
        
  m_charactedRangeProperties.Add(newGuy, formatting);
}

public bool Remove (CharacterRange theKey) {
  // true if the element is successfully removed; otherwise, false.
  // also returns false if key is not found

  if (theKey == null) return false;  //throws exception if removed attempted

  return m_charactedRangeProperties.Remove(theKey);
}
```

*WHY* we want to Add or Remove is not in those respective methods. Generally a collection is responsible for the *collection* data integrity and its use is driven by other classes.

*Why* is currently in `handleIntersectingCharacterRanges`, et.al. Maybe each `if` clause is a separate method. Maybe the overall logic process is spread across a driver, a CharacterRangeProcessor, CharacterRange, and the collection class. I don't know enough to assess the overall design.

---

---

**CompareTo, HashCode, & Multiple-Property-Equality**

Here is a comment made earlier:  [equal hash codes do not imply object equality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35866246/463206)

I'm making a wild guess: `HashCode` is used in `CompareTo` because the equality properties are hashed together, making for a simple comparison. But the linked SO answer says that's not a good idea.

**`CompareTo` with multiple properties**

```
public int CompareTo(CharacterRange other) {
  if (other == null) return 1;
  if (this.start > other.start) return 1;
  if (this.start < other.start) return -1;

  // the start's are equal so ...
  return CompareEnds(other);
}

protected int CompareEnds(CharacterRange other) {
  if (other == null) return 1;
  if (this.end < other.end) return -1;
  if (this.end > other.end return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good points on the comparisons, I honestly don't know why I compared the hash codes. I also get your points on the ```PartialFormatting``` class being some kind of custom collection class, but I don't see the point separating it into a "collection" and a "driver" class. Your proposed ```Add``` and ```Remove``` functions just add and remove from the dictionary, with only an added null check. I don't think this merits a whole class just to wrap the existing functions of the ```SortedDictionary```.

Comment: *I don't see the point separating it into a "collection" and a "driver" class.*  -> It's the "S" in SOLID; it's about maximizing cohesion while minimizing coupling; overall code simplification thru good Single Responsibility application; OO  features help class design has some inherent extensibility

Comment: *just to wrap the existing functions of the SortedDictionary.*  ->  NO!  It's about having a collection of `CharacterRange` that does not also create and mutate objects. Adding to SortedDictionary so it creates and mutates `CharacterRange` objects is absurd. So it is for any collection class.

Comment: *I don't think this merits a whole class*  ->  Why use a whole `SortedDictionary` class when only calling `Add()`? It is just a couple of stupid integers. Is the program simple bits of arithmetic and rudimentary logic or about doing things with "CharacterRanges?"  Why weigh down a perfectly good class with toy-like parts and make it so complex? Don't buy a radio controlled race car when all you need to do is throw 4 tiny tires down the street. Just write the code already and don't make something so simple so hard.

Comment: I think that is a really good point, the whole reason I used ```SortedDictionary``` in the first place, was because initially I wanted a unique key,value relationship between ```CharacterRange``` and ```Formatting``` (hence ```Dictionary```), but I wanted to also sort them so I ended up with ```SortedDictionary```. It would probably be cleaner if I just used a ```Dictionary``` and sorted the results by key when I wanted to use them.

Comment: Using `SortedDictionary` is a good idea. Since it's self-sorting and keyed there's not much need for various `Sort` and `Find` methods you'd write if it was a `List`, let's say.  However having to write more, or less, code is *never* a reason to create a class, or not. You need a collection; it should be a domain specific class.